# Vertex List Coloring Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Is there any (preferably simple) algorithm to check list-coloring for small planar graphs?

I searched and found many bounds-on-list-chromatic numbers and some results on edge list coloring.

I could not find any simple way to, say, set up the $k$-size lists for a $(m,n)$-bipartite graph to show that $\chi_l > k$ (on the wikipedia page there is an explanation and found a few examples e.g. for $K_{2,4}$ but no method for general list lengths).

Comment: You want an algorithm to check, given a coloring, that it is a valid list coloring?

Comment: No, given a list length k for a graph G (simple cases), I want to prove or disprove that G is k-choosable.

Comment: e.g. I am given K2,4 say. Then for list length 3, I want to prove list coloring is possible for any assignment (for this case I can, but maybe there is a general method) and I want to find (by a method; rather than inspection) that 2-size list that proves K2,4 is NOT 2-choosable